# increasingly high latency in node.js multiplayer html5 game

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express, socket.io

I created a webpage using node.js, express js, socket.io, and jquery. It is a simple game wherein players join, give themselves a name, and then move themselves(a square) around a canvas on the page. What I've noticed is: when more people join the game and move around, there is enough lag to make the game unplayable (at only three people connected. Two people doesn't lag it much). I can't figure out if this is server-side lag or client-side (this is my first project dealing with multiplayer). I am doing all of the location calculations on the server, and sending an array of all the player objects back to every socket so that each client can render all of the players. The client only sends input and draws the players.

This is the client side script for the game. This is where I handle the input and rendering.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var socket = io.connect();

 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_html");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
 canvas.width = 512;
 canvas.height = 480;
  
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 var player = 
 {
  id: '',
  is_it: false,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  velx: 0,
  vely: 0
 }
    
    //tell the server to initialize this client as a new player
 socket.emit('init_client', player);
    
 var client_player_list = [];
    
    //receive a list of the player objects from the server
 socket.on('load_players', function(players)
 {
  client_player_list = players;
 });

 var keysDown = {};

 addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
 {
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
 }, false);

 addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
 {
  delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
 }, false);

 //take input from keys and send input to server
 var update = function()
 {
  if(87 in keysDown)//player holding w
   socket.emit('up');
  if(83 in keysDown)//player holding s
   socket.emit('down');
  if(65 in keysDown)//player holding a
   socket.emit('left');
  if(68 in keysDown)//player holding d
   socket.emit('right');
  if(74 in keysDown)//player holding j
   socket.emit('tag');
 };

 //render all players, update players when server updates
 var render = function()
 {
  //ctx.clearColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)";
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#079641";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      
        //loop through the players array and render each one
  for(var i = 0; i < client_player_list.length; i++)
  {
            //if the player is_it, render them as red
   if(client_player_list[i].is_it)
   { 
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8F0E0E";
    ctx.fillRect(client_player_list[i].x, client_player_list[i].y, 20, 20);
                
                //draw the players name above them
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
    ctx.font="15px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(client_player_list[i].name, client_player_list[i].x + 8, client_player_list[i].y - 3);
    continue;
   }
            
            //if the player !is_it, render them as green
            ctx.fillStyle = "#079641";
   ctx.fillRect(client_player_list[i].x, client_player_list[i].y, 20, 20);
            
            //draw the players name above them
   ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
   ctx.font="15px Arial";
   ctx.fillText(client_player_list[i].name, client_player_list[i].x + 8, client_player_list[i].y - 3);
  }
         
        //when the server sends an update, replace the current players array with the one that the server just sent
  socket.on('sv_update', function(players)
  {
   client_player_list = players;
  });
 };

 //main loop
 var main = function()
 {
  setInterval(function()
  {
   update();
   render();
  }, 1000/60);
 };

 main();

 //trigger the disconnect event when a page refreshes or unloads
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function()
 {
  socket.emit('disconnect');
 });
});
```

Below, I have included the app.js file (the server-side script) for my game. I am not sure exactly where the problem is, so I figured I'd just post the whole thing.

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io', { rememberTransport: false, transports: ['WebSocket', 'Flash Socket', 'AJAX long-polling'] });

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static('public'));

io = io.listen(server);

//Declare variables for working with the client-side
var player_speed = 5;
var player_size = 20;
var vel_increment = 0.5;
var canvas_height = 480;
var canvas_width = 512;

//Declare list of players connected
var players = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  var socket_id = socket.id;
  var player_index, player_exists = false;
  var this_player;

  var check_bounds = function()
  {
    //Keep player in the canvas
    if(this_player.y < 0)
        this_player.y = 0;
    if(this_player.y + player_size > canvas_height)
        this_player.y = canvas_height - player_size;

    if(this_player.x < 0)
      this_player.x = 0;
    if(this_player.x + player_size > canvas_width)
      this_player.x = canvas_width - player_size;

    //Keep velocity between -5 and 5
    if(this_player.vely > player_speed)
      this_player.vely = player_speed;
    if(this_player.velx > player_speed)
      this_player.velx = player_speed;

    if(this_player.vely < -player_speed)
      this_player.vely = -player_speed;
    if(this_player.velx < -player_speed)
      this_player.velx = -player_speed;
  };

  var sv_update = function()
  {
    io.sockets.emit('sv_update', players);
    if(player_exists)
    {
      if(players.length == 1)
        this_player.is_it = true;
      check_bounds();
    }
  };
  
  //When a client connects, add them to players[]
  //Then update all clients
  socket.on('init_client', function(player)
  {
    player.id = socket.id;
    players.push(player);

    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
      if(players[i].id == socket_id)
        player_index = i;
    player_exists = true;
    this_player = players[player_index];

    sv_update();
    socket.emit('load_players', players);

    console.log(players);
  });

  //====================CHAT==========================//
  var address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;

  socket.on('new user', function(data, callback)
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      this_player.name = data;
      console.log(address + " has connected as '" + data + "'.");
      
      callback();
    }
  });

  socket.on('send message', function(data)
  {
    io.sockets.emit('broadcast', this_player.name, data);
  });
  //====================CHAT==========================//
  
  //if player is_it and is within another player, hitting 'j' will make the other player is_it. 
  socket.on('tag', function()
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
      {
        if((this_player.x + player_size >= players[i].x && this_player.x + player_size <= players[i].x + player_size )|| 
          (this_player.x <= players[i].x + player_size && this_player.x + player_size >= players[i].x))
          if((this_player.y + player_size >= players[i].y && this_player.y + player_size <= players[i].y + player_size )|| 
          (this_player.y <= players[i].y + player_size && this_player.y + player_size >= players[i].y))
          {
            if(this_player.is_it)
            {
              this_player.is_it = false;
              players[i].is_it = true;
            }
          }
      }
      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //Gather key input from users...
  socket.on('up', function()
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      this_player.y -= player_speed;

      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //Gather key input from users...
  socket.on('down', function()
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      this_player.y += player_speed;

      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //Gather key input from users...
  socket.on('left', function()
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
     this_player.x -= player_speed;

      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //Gather key input from users...
  socket.on('right', function()
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      this_player.x += player_speed;

      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //When a player disconnects, remove them from players[]
  //Then update all clients
  socket.on('disconnect', function()
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
    {
      if(players[i].id == socket.id)
      {
        players.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }

    sv_update();
  });
});
```

--------------------------------------------------------- EDIT ------------------------------------------------------------------ I took Ruslanas Balčiūnas's suggestion for moving the sv_update handler in the client out of the render function. This stops the player from lagging, but the new problem is that the server doesn't send enough updates for all the players to move fluidly on any given client. Each client seems to be running smoothly for just themselves, but the other clients see them as choppy/lagging.

Here is the updated code:

CLIENT:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 var socket = io.connect();

 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_html");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.width = 512;
 canvas.height = 480;

 document.body.appendChild(canvas);

 var player = 
 {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  is_it: false,
  x: canvas.width / 2,
  y: canvas.height / 2,
  velx: 0,
  vely: 0
 };

 var client_player_list = [];
 socket.on('load_players', function(players)
 {
  client_player_list = players;
 });

 var keysDown = {};

 addEventListener('keydown', function(e)
 {
  keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
 }, false);

 addEventListener('keyup', function(e)
 {
  delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
 }, false);

 //take input from keys and send input to server
 var update = function()
 {
  if(87 in keysDown)//player holding w
   socket.emit('input', 'up');
  if(83 in keysDown)//player holding s
   socket.emit('input', 'down');
  if(65 in keysDown)//player holding a
   socket.emit('input', 'left');
  if(68 in keysDown)//player holding d
   socket.emit('input', 'right');
  if(74 in keysDown)
   socket.emit('input', 'tag');
 };

 //render all players, update players when server updates
 var render = function()
 {
  //ctx.clearColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)";
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#079641";
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';

  for(var i = 0; i < client_player_list.length; i++)
  {
   if(client_player_list[i].is_it)
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8F0E0E";
   else
    ctx.fillStyle = "#079641";

   ctx.fillRect(client_player_list[i].x, client_player_list[i].y, 25, 25);

   ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
   ctx.font="15px Arial";
   ctx.fillText(client_player_list[i].name, client_player_list[i].x + 8, client_player_list[i].y - 3);
  }
 };

 socket.on('sv_update', function(players)
 {
  client_player_list = players;
 });

 //main loop
 var main = function()
 {
  setInterval(function()
  {
   update();
   render();
  }, 1000/60);
 };

 main();

 //---- Chat stuff ----
 var toggle = 1;

 $('#users').fadeIn(1000);
 $('#name_field').focus();

 $('#user_form').submit(function(e)
 {
  console.log('ezpz');
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('init_client', player, $('#name_field').val(), function()
  {
   $('#users').fadeOut('slow');
   window.setTimeout(function(){$('#chat').fadeIn('slow');$('#canvas_html').fadeIn('slow');$('#info').fadeIn('slow')}, 1000);
  });
 });

 $('#desk').submit(function(e)
 {
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('send message', $('#message').val());
  $('#message').val('');
 });

 socket.on('broadcast', function(name, data)
 {
  $('#message_window').append('<p class="p' + toggle + '">' + name + ": " + data + '</p>');
  $('#message_window')[0].scrollTop = $('#message_window')[0].scrollHeight;

  if(toggle == 1)
   toggle = 2;
  else
   toggle = 1;
 });

 //trigger the disconnect event when a page refreshes or unloads
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function()
 {
  socket.emit('disconnect');
 });
});
```

SERVER:

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io', { rememberTransport: false, transports: ['WebSocket', 'Flash Socket', 'AJAX long-polling'] });

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080);

app.use(express.static('public'));

io = io.listen(server);

//Declare variables for working with the client-side
var player_speed = 5;
var player_size = 25;
var canvas_height = 480;
var canvas_width = 512;

//Declare list of players connected
var players = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{
  var socket_id = socket.id;
  var player_index, this_player, player_exists = false;

  //When a client connects, add them to players[]
  //Then update all clients
  socket.on('init_client', function(player, name, callback)
  {
    player.id = socket.id;
    players.push(player);

    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
      if(players[i].id == socket_id)
        player_index = i;
    player_exists = true;
    this_player = players[player_index];

    this_player.name = name;
    callback();

    sv_update();
    socket.emit('load_players', players);
  });

  socket.on('send message', function(data)
  {
    io.sockets.emit('broadcast', this_player.name, data);
  });

  //Gather key input from users...
  socket.on('input', function(key)
  {
    if(player_exists)
    {
      if(key == 'up')
        this_player.y -= player_speed;
      else if(key == 'down')
        this_player.y += player_speed;
      else if(key == 'left')
        this_player.x -= player_speed;
      else if(key == 'right')
        this_player.x += player_speed;
      else if(key == 'tag')
        for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
          if(can_tag(players[i]))
          {
            this_player.is_it = false;
            players[i].is_it = true;
          }

      sv_update();
    }
  });

  //When a player disconnects, remove them from players[]
  //Then update all clients
  socket.on('disconnect', function()
  {
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++)
      if(players[i].id == socket.id)
        players.splice(i, 1);

    sv_update();
  });

  var check_bounds = function()
  {
    //Keep player in the canvas
    if(this_player.y < 0)
        this_player.y = 0;
    if(this_player.y + player_size > canvas_height)
        this_player.y = canvas_height - player_size;

    if(this_player.x < 0)
      this_player.x = 0;
    if(this_player.x + player_size > canvas_width)
      this_player.x = canvas_width - player_size;
  };

  var sv_update = function()
  {
    io.sockets.emit('sv_update', players);
    if(player_exists)
    {
      if(players.length == 1)
        this_player.is_it = true;
      check_bounds();
    }
  };

  var can_tag = function(target)
  {
    if(this_player.x < target.x + player_size && this_player.x + player_size > target.x && this_player.y < target.y + player_size && player_size + this_player.y > target.y && this_player.is_it)
      return true;
  }

  sv_update();
});
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Move below code from render function in client side.

```
//when the server sends an update, replace the current players array with the one that the server just sent
socket.on('sv_update', function(players)
{
    client_player_list = players;
});
```

Comment: Well, this did manage to help with the lag, but only for each person's own player on their own screen. Now, when you play the game, everybody is laggy except for you. I think this has to do with the fact that perhaps the server isn't sending enough updates? I really don't know, though. I will experiment with that and get back to you. Meanwhile if you have any suggestions, I would gladly take them.

Comment: Maybe should redesign the whole way the game communicates. My experimentation with realtime gave me some conclusions on this point:
- Send small datas together at a certain interval instead of sending them separately, to avoid packet overhead.
- Do as much as you can on the client side, to keep your server's response quick as possible.
In this case, it makes sense to send a player movement instantly instead of buffering say 50ms of movement and then send them.
But I thing could make some improvements, like sending only the new position of the player instead of the whole array.

Comment: You should also define an interval at which the player can actually move instead of sending a packet each time the browser receive a `keydown/keyup` event. Because when you press a key and don't release it, it still sends a packet. That's the bottleneck I guess

Comment: Do you think you cold post some pseudo code on how to accomplish this? I think I understand what you're suggesting, but I am not sure about the best way to do it.